# Show that $d_2$ is not a metric.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Show that the function $d_2$ given by $d_2(f_1, f_2)^2 = \int_a^b{(f_1
>  - f_2)^2}$ is not a metric space on the space of Riemann integrable functions on $[a,b]$.

1. $d_2(f_1, f_2) = 0$ iff $f_1 = f_2$.
2. $d_2(f_1, f_2) = d_2(f_2, f_1)$.
3. (Triangle inequality) Not sure, actually...

My book says that $d_2$ is a valid metric on the space of continuous functions. Is there something about Riemann integrable functions that is different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $f_1$ and $f_2$ differ in values just at let us say in the middle of the interval, thus at a point, this would not change the integral value, it would vanish, but $f_1$ and $f_2$ would be considered different.